# Why do we need to ask javac to compile multiple source files?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

This is a very basic question which I am unable to find a satisfiable answer yet.

If I have two classes `TestCar.java` `Car.java` in my directory, when I execute a `javac TestCar.java` the program successfully compiles and it results in creating two .class files for each class.

I only asked the compiler to compile `TestCar.java` , but somehow the compiler figured out that it needs to compile the `Car.java` file as well. If that is how it works I should be able to ask `javac` to compile only the main class of my program and it should be able to compile all the .java files the program depends on. If that's true, why do we need to issue commands like `javac *.java` or `javac dir1/*.java dir2/*java` and so on?

Even when using packages we should be able to compile all the files by executing

```
javac com/project/MainClass.java
```

and the compiler should be able to compile all the files the program depends on. So why all these questions about "`how to compile multiple java files`" ?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler isn't that smart. It can't know what classes you use by reflection for example, so it only works for the most basic cases.

That's why we have build systems like ant, maven or gradle that handle compilation without having to manually type all the needed classes.

Comment: Actually the compiler is very very smart - it's just dumb about stuff it shouldn't need worry about like dependencies and stuff which can be handled by the tools you mentioned.

Comment: If my program does not use reflection, i should be able to compile like I have mentioned (compiling only the main class)?

Comment: @DesirePRG No. I recommend looking at maven or gradle for a build system.

Answer (score 1):

The javac tool reads class and interface definitions, written in the Java programming language, and compiles them into bytecode class files. It can also process annotations in Java source files and classes.

There are two ways to pass source code file names to javac:

For a small number of source files, simply list the file names on the command line.
For a large number of source files, list the file names in a file, separated by blanks or line breaks. Then use the list file name on the javac command line, preceded by an @ character.
Source code file names must have .java suffixes, class file names must have .class suffixes, and both source and class files must have root names that identify the class. For example, a class called MyClass would be written in a source file called MyClass.java and compiled into a bytecode class file called MyClass.class.

Inner class definitions produce additional class files. These class files have names combining the inner and outer class names, such as MyClass$MyInnerClass.class.

You should arrange source files in a directory tree that reflects their package tree. For example, if you keep all your source files in C:\workspace, the source code for com.mysoft.mypack.MyClass should be in C:\workspace\com\mysoft\mypack\MyClass.java.

By default, the compiler puts each class file in the same directory as its source file